# Why is Yfinance library for months not working?

Tags: python, datetime, httpresponse, yahoo-finance

I am using the Yahoo finance library and the requests library in python. When I try to call historic data for ranges of months or years, like "1mo" or "1y" I get the error 422.

I tried to call another stock and different month periods like 3 months, but it is the same result. This is the code I use, which gives me the error code 422:

```
import requests

def fetch_yahoo_finance_data(symbol, interval='1m', range_='1mo'):
    url 
    =f"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/{symbol}? 
    interval={interval}&range={range_}"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        return data
    else:
        print(f"Failed to fetch data. Status 
        Code{response.status_code}")
        return None

data = fetch_yahoo_finance_data('BMW.DE', "1m", "1mo")
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is all the code I used.

Comment: What is an example that fails?  Are you changing both interval and range?

Comment: there is invalid syntax in the code at line `url=f"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/{symbol}? interval={interval}&range={range_}"`

Comment: also,  `headers` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

i use the yahoo finance module `yfinance` to achieve the same (as opposed to using the URL method attmepted in the question which had an undefined `headers` variable).

this is the code that i use:

```py
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Define the ticker symbol for BMW. Use "BMW.DE" for the Frankfurt Stock Exchange.
ticker_symbol = "BMW.DE"

# Create a ticker object
bmw_ticker = yf.Ticker(ticker_symbol)

# Calculate the date 6 months ago from today
six_months_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=6*30)  # Approximation of 6 months

# Fetch the historical data for BMW for the last 6 months
bmw_data = bmw_ticker.history(
    start=six_months_ago.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), 
    end=datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

# Display the closing prices
print(bmw_data['Close'])
```

And the result look like this:

```
Date
2023-07-18 00:00:00+02:00    107.099998
2023-07-19 00:00:00+02:00    107.199997
2023-07-20 00:00:00+02:00    107.680000
2023-07-21 00:00:00+02:00    107.580002
2023-07-24 00:00:00+02:00    108.599998
                                ...    
2024-01-08 00:00:00+01:00    101.199997
2024-01-09 00:00:00+01:00    100.820000
2024-01-10 00:00:00+01:00     99.900002
2024-01-11 00:00:00+01:00     98.459999
2024-01-12 00:00:00+01:00     96.849998
Name: Close, Length: 125, dtype: float64
```